Joblib parallel processing introduces {built-in method time.sleep} in profiling
I am using Joblib to run parallel jobs in my Python application. During profiling, I noticed that the slowest process was {built-in method time.sleep}. Interestingly, this issue disappears when I remove Joblib parallel processing. Could you explain why {built-in method time.sleep} becomes a bottleneck with Joblib parallel processing?
Here is a simplified version of my code:
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def my_function(x):
    # Some computation
    return x * x

results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(my_function)(i) for i in range(10))

Profiling Output
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    17153  209.317    0.012  209.317    0.012 {built-in method time.sleep}
      588    0.835    0.001    0.835    0.001 {method 'poll' of 'select.poll' objects}


Presumably because the parent process you're profiling is waiting for the child processes that are doing the work to become ready, and are doing that with time.sleep().
You can verify this with a profiler that shows you the call graph – if my guess is correct, one of the top callers to time.sleep() is somewhere within joblib. My guess is it's this code.
